# Extension for generic constrained to another generic in swift

Tags: swift, generics

Consider the following situation, where `T1` and `T2` can be of any type.

```
class Foo<T1> {}
class Bar<T2> {}
```

I need an extension for `Foo` where `T1` is `Bar<T2>`. It seems very obvious, but the questions is rather ambiguous – I can't find much information on this. Compiler complains with the following messages:

```
extension Foo where T1:Bar {} // Error: reference to generic type 'Bar' requires arguments in <...>
extension Foo where T1:Bar<T2> {} // Error: use of undeclared type 'T2'

extension Foo where T1:Bar<Any> {
    func test() { Swift.print(self) }
}

let foo = Foo<Bar<NSObject>>()
foo.test() // Error: 'Bar<NSObject>' is not a subtype of 'Bar<Any>'
```

Comment: Qux and Bar are just generic placeholders, you know you havent defined them as classes?!

Comment: Yep, that wasn't very clear, thanks for pointing out. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo<T1> {}
class Bar<T2> {}

extension Foo where T1:Bar<NSObject> { // instead of Any
    func test() { Swift.print(self) }
}

let foo = Foo<Bar<NSObject>>()
foo.test()
// output: CfsdikgLiC.Foo<CfsdikgLiC.Bar<Foundation.NSObject>>
```

Is that OK? Or another version:

```
class Foo<T1> {}
class Bar<T2> {}

extension Foo where T1:Bar<Any> { 
    func test() { Swift.print(self) }
}

let foo = Foo<Bar<Any>>() // instead of NSObject
foo.test()
// output: T8fT4XJI7R.Foo<T8fT4XJI7R.Bar<Any>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried the first case, it doesn't work, see the updated question. In you example it would compile fine, but as soon as something is added into the extension and used, it fails with types that don't match up.

Comment: Interesting question. Answer is Updated.

Comment: Thanks for looking further, but I need `T2` to be any value. After deeper digging, apparently, this is not possible yet with Swift, as generics are still under active improvement – keep an eye on it [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3716).